# Backbone.js on save() is posting to create instead of Update and with JS instead of JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to use a Backbone.js model to keep track of what guides a user has seen. I would like to store the value in User.guides which is a serialized field in rails.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/users',
    defaults : {
        user : {
            guides : {
                step1 : false,
                step2 : false           
            }           
        }
    }

});
```

That's what happens on load. Later on when I try to make an update:

```
me.model.set({
    user : {
        room_wizard : {
            project_completed : true
        }           
    }
});


me.model.save();
```

The problem here is Rails is erroring for the following reasons:

- Backbone.js is posting to create as JS when it should be Update as JSON? Why?

Ideas? Am I handling the above incorrectly? I'm new to backbone.js Thanks

Comment: The issue might be that with rails + devise, to update current user's user model, you post to /users instead of /users/:id --- Is there a way to handle this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Backbone's rule of thumb for choosing between `POST` or `PUT` to the server is if the Model has an `id` or has not.

- If Model **has** an `id` Backbone will use the verb `PUT`.
- If Model **has not** an `id` Backbone will use the verb `POST`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but given Rails is not setup this way for the User model, how can I override?

Comment: The `User` Model has not `id` in the Rails layer? how are you gonna know which `User` are you _updating_?.